# Execute a command after opening a terminal in which ssh is used to log into remote machine

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I wish to open a new terminal, ssh to a remote machine in the opened terminal which has to be kept open  and a command has to be executed in this terminal in foreground.

The following command opens a new terminal in which a remote machine is logged in:

`gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=NOCLOSEPROFILE -e "ssh -X $user@$IPaddress"`

(Say 'ls' is the command to be executed in foreground in the terminal newly opened)I tried the following command:

`gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=NOCLOSEPROFILE -e "ssh -X $user@$IPaddress&&ls"`

But this command opened a terminal without ssh-ing into the remote machine, paused for a while and it closed. Let me know what is wrong in this command and how to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

You're running ssh and then running ls after the ssh command exits.  You need

```
"ssh -X $user@$host 'command to run on host'"
```

Comment: This command will give the output in current terminal itself. I want the output to appear in the new terminal and the terminal to be kept open even after the command has finished executing. This terminal should be open for entering commands manually after this command has finished its execution.

Comment: Change the command to `'command;/bin/bash'` and add a `-t` after the ssh to force allocation of a pseudoterminal (so the shell will work).